# JMeter Document upload - Content validation in converted pdf document

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

W.r.t. JMeter document upload and download,
I would like to know, Can we validate and do ample to ample content comparison (e.g. same Text, Space, Lines, Images etc) of PDF document which is converted using Libra Office/PDF Box in Document upload scenarios from different type of documents like Doc/Docx/Text/Jpg/Png/Rtf etc

Scenario-

- Upload a Docx document ( Document should convert in PDF Format and user can view the same in pdf)
- View the Docx Document in PDF Format after document upload

-Compare the Docx Contents (e.g. Text, Space, Lines, Images etc) in PDF doc, is same or not

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) project, if you add the tika-app.jar to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you would be able to use `Document (text)` "Field to Test" of the [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion):

[image]

so you can check document content against reference text.

If it is not sufficient for your needs take a look at [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) APIs